# Spring Batch Write lines before valid csv header

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have generated a csv file from my DB using spring batch. However I need to add multiple line (total count of rows, value and current date, value ) before the actual header..data. Any Ideas ?

records_count,10
date,2020-0301
----header----
---data----

Comment: Can you calculate `records_count` upfront? If yes, then you can do it in a header callback or in a separate step (which is cleaner IMO).

Comment: can you update more record examples?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FlatFileHeaderCallback` to write headers. 
for example

```
public class CsvHeaderCallback implements FlatFileHeaderCallback {
    @Override
    public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException {
        //your logic here
        //writer.write("records_count,10 date,2020-0301");
    }
}
```

You can inject this bean to `headerCallback` property of `FlatFileItemWriter`

or in your writer

```
public class MyFlatFileWriter extends FlatFileItemWriter {

public MyFlatFileWriter (){
    super.setHeaderCallback(new FlatFileHeaderCallback() {

        public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException {
         //your logic here
        //writer.write("records_count,10 date,2020-0301");

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you response, I already have the header in my output file, But i need to qadd 3 lines about header somehitng like the sample i shared

Comment: VersionNo V1.0                                                                                                                                
RecordsCount 2                                                                                                             
TotalAmount 4287                                                                                                
source id reference
Loc 1 1
Loc 2 2

Comment: before writing actual header, you can write the logic to fetch and write the details in file using `FlatFileHeaderCallback` implementation. `public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException {
        writer.write("VersionNo V1.0 RecordsCount 2 TotalAmount 4287");
        writer.write("source id reference Loc 1 1 Loc 2 2");
        }`